# SVG chalk line troubles

Tags: jquery, svg, design-patterns, raphael, border

for a project I would like to draw a chalk-like border around a SVG rectangle object. I managed to add a pattern to a 4px wide line and this does resemble chalk somewhat, but I am actually looking into making the line more realistic.

What I have tried so far is creating a chalk like texture in Illustrator and exporting this to SVG, but how can I than import this SVG file as pattern in my existing SVG without having to copy all the path information by hand? And how can I make this texture as efficient as possible so the viewer won't have to load 23 MB of path information?

I hope you guys can help me out.

Cheers,

Hide

P.S. This is what I have come up with so far:

[SVG Chalk like line as far as I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExkPf.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd suggest using [svg filters](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html), if you just want to quickly experiment, open your file in [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org), select one of your rectangles, then add a "Chalk and sponge" filter, and play with the parameters until you get something you're happy with.

That's just a start, but you can get quite nice results from that, here's an example:

```
    <filter id="chalk" height="2" width="1.6" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" y="-0.5" x="-0.3">
        <feTurbulence baseFrequency="0.32065" seed="115" result="result1" numOctaves="1" type="turbulence"/>
        <feOffset result="result2" dx="-5" dy="-5"/>
        <feDisplacementMap scale="10" yChannelSelector="G" in2="result1" xChannelSelector="R" in="SourceGraphic"/>
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1.1169"/>
    </filter>
```

Then you use that on shapes and text as needed, like this for example:

```
    <text filter="url(#chalk)" font-size="26px" fill="white">f(x) = 4x + 7</text>
    <rect filter="url(#chalk)" width="150" stroke="#FFF" stroke-dasharray="16,4" stroke-width="4" fill="none"/>
```

Comment: Because I wanted to see this, I've put it online here: http://jsfiddle.net/kDem5/ Nice work, Erik! :) Tweaking the parameters a little, here's a slightly less blurry, tighter version of the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/kDem5/2/

Comment: And...with a background image and coloring: http://jsfiddle.net/kDem5/3/ ... and then varying the dasharray so that the strokes aren't so regular: http://jsfiddle.net/kDem5/4/ And finally(!) a use for Comic Sans that doesn't suck: http://jsfiddle.net/kDem5/5/

Comment: Thanks guys, great work it has really helped me along. I was stuck on trying out different patterns but couldn't get much further than something that looked like a tire track ;)